# Bad audit in LQP queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

How does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876250/why-my-email-is-looking-different-in-two-gmail-accounts) look good?

It doesn't show any [MCVE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231), just two screenshots of the two different outcomes

TBH, I don't know how that question got so many upvotes.

Here is the audit:

[image]

Comment: Only on SO are people upset about a week's vacation :P.

Comment: Ahahahah true, I don't like vacations on SO, beside SO **I LOVE VACATIONS** `:)`

Comment: Don't forget one audit failure will not give you a ban, it takes other review failures for the ban to kick in.

Comment: Audits just check if you vote like everybody else did.  So sure, if you CV a question that has 5 helpful votes and no close votes then you are getting it wrong.  We got so much crap around these days because SO users like crap.  Not remembering that you failed an audit *multiple* times is, well, not a great hint that you are paying attention either.

Comment: If I remember right review bans do not start at 7 days but grow to that amount the more they are received.

Comment: The suspension ban is implemented not only for this review, but for your other failures.

Comment: There should be an "I disagree" button or similar. I don't know what it would do, but I simply refuse to use the "I understand" button in cases like this. I just close the tab and start over from another tab instead.

Comment: @NisseEngström agreed

Comment: Wow, how did that question get so many upvotes!!  It would be interesting to audit those votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad audit that was automatically chosen due to the number of upvotes on the question.

I have downvoted and voted to close the question for the reason "lacks MCVE" so hopefully it will be closed and no longer appear as an audit.

Comment: exactly the reason why I failed the audit, closing for no MCVE

Comment: @dippas just remember audits are automatically selected from posts who got a "clear" response(good, bad, closed, whatever) from the community. When you see an inaccurate audit like that, your best action is to take the PROPER action o. the post, as JAL did. Now that this post got a close vote, it wont be an audit anymore. Doesnt help your failed audit... But helps others not fall prey to it

Comment: @Patrice I did that ;)

Comment: @Dippas so will i as soon as i hit add comment here lol. It's a shame as it doesnt help with your failed audit..